# Real time analytics with Python and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, analytics, pymongo

I am a Python beginner working on a very basic real-time analytics tool using Python and MongoDB.
I have a function that updates a collection of URLs and pageviews stored in MongoDB:

```
def track(url):
   hour = datetime.utcnow().replace(minute = 0, second = 0, microsecond = 0)
   db.hourly.update({"hour": hour, "url":url}, {"$inc": {"views": 1}}, upsert = True)
   db.hourly_totals.update({"hour": hour}, {"$inc": {"views": 1}}, upsert = True)
```

Whenever track gets executed for a given URL, the collection of documents gets updated accordingly with pageviews for each URL incremented for collection "hourly", and total pageviews for all urls incremented for collection "hourly_totals".

What is the best way to automate this process such that track gets executed every time somebody visits a page on my website? Could I do this in Python or do I have to embed this in a Javascript tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can place javascript (JQuery) code (in document.ready() method) which makes a call to a web service which in turn executes this track method. If you just want a simple web server for your webservice, use [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/).